# I have been trying to create a simple atm program, I am lost

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with an ATM python program that I am creating. I am new to Python and I am worried that my coding is so off that I must start from the beginning. I am trying to separate the sections by `def ():` and I keep getting an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled3.py", line 44, in <module>
    deposit()
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled3.py", line 35, in deposit
    if (answer == "D") or (answer == "d"):
NameError: global name 'answer' is not defined
```

I have been searching a long time and trying to grasp the concepts of Python the best I can. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Here is my code:

## The purpose of this program is to create a simple ATM environment

## Written by K. Strobach 11/22/13

```
def account():
    print ("Hello, welcome to Bank of Python!")
    print ("Please enter your account pin number")
    account = raw_input("Account pin number is 1234: ")
    account = (1234)

account()

def balance():
    print ("would you like to see your account balance?")
    see = raw_input("Enter Y or N: ")
    if (see == "Y") or (see == "y"):
        balance = int(0)
    print ("Current balance: $" + str(balance))

balance()

def transaction():
    print ("Would you like to make a transaction?")
    more = raw_input("Enter Y or N: ")

    if (more == "Y") or (more == "y"):
        print ("Would you like to make a deposit or withdraw? Or would you like to end this transaction?")
    answer = raw_input("Enter D for deposit; W for withdraw; E for end: ")

transaction()

def deposit():
    if (answer == "D") or (answer == "d"):
        print ("How much would you like to deposit?")
        deposit = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")
        deposit = int(deposit)

        currentbalance = deposit + balance
        print ("Deposited: $" + str(deposit))
        print ("Current Balance: $" + str(currentbalance))

deposit()

def withdraw():    
    if (answer == "W") or (answer == "w"):
        print ("How much would you like to withdrawl?")
        withdraw = input("Enter amount to withdraw: ")
        withdraw = int(withdraw)

        currentbalance = withdraw - balance
        print ("Withdrew: $" + str(withdraw))
        print ("Current Balance: $" + str(currentbalance))

withdraw()        

def end():
    if (answer == "E") or (answer == "e"):
        exit ("Thank you for Banking with Bank of Python, goodbye!")

    else:
        exit ("Thank you for Banking with Bank of Python, goodbye!")

end()
```

This is for a class, but I am not worried about that, I just want to get a better understanding of how to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accept whichever answer you feel helped you the most. It may be useful for those who come next to know the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that this was about learning, and I really respect that, so I'm going to offer a totally unsolicited review of the code you wrote as a whole, trying to point out stylistic and substantive improvements where I saw some. I'm sure you could get more competent help, but I wanted feedback like this from someone who was a little further along than me. The short answer has already been pointed out, that you're not assigning `answer` before referencing it within that function, but there are other things worth noting as well.

In the interest of keeping the short answer relevant, I also point to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) good answer on how scoping works for Python. If you just want to know why `answer` wasn't working right, that should clear things up. If you want a really tedious breakdown of the code, read on :)

## account

Let's look at `account` first. I'll only say this once, but you *can* (although are by no means obligated to) `print` multi-line strings. You can do this a number of ways:

```
print("This line\nwill print on\nthree lines!")
```

prints...

```
This line
will print on
three lines!
```

The key here being the newline character `\n`. Notice that I said it was a character, not character**s**. That will come up someday.

An alternative way to print multi-line strings is by making the string multi-line using triple quotation marks:

```
print('''This line
will print on
three lines!''')
```

prints... well, the same thing as above. People are not as keen on this approach since triple quotes are often used for block comments and [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings), but there's no law against it.

While we're in `account` I want you to consider the logic of this pair of statements:

```
account = raw_input("Account pin number is 1234: ")
account = (1234)
```

What this is doing is prompting the user to enter a pin number, and then setting it to `(1234)` regardless. This might be intentional - like for testing purposes - but it seems weird to me. I'm also not sure if you're trying to create a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (which would just require a trailing comma), but if *not*, and you're just making a simple integer, you can say

```
account = 1234
```

which will disambiguate the intent a little bit.

I'll also bring up that [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is a python 2.x function, and in python 3k you just use [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input). you should be cautious, however, to convert the value the user gives into the appropriate type: `input` returns a `string` type regardless of what the user enters. You can quickly convert it into an integer by calling `int(input("some prompt"))`, but you might want to catch errors, like if someone responds to that prompt with "I'm lost and not good with computers."

## balance

When you ask if the user wants to see their balance, you set it to 0!

```
balance = int(0)
```

Not necessary, and in fact somewhat frustrating for anyone doing business at the Bank of Python.

This is also potentially a little too advanced for you, but consider using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to print the balance. It's a nice way of taking care of the little odds and ends in a simple function. In this case, you'd use something like

```
print("Current balance: ${b:.2f}".format(b=balance))
```

## transaction

So I accidentally skipped ahead and saw that you planned on using `answer` in a later function. You're thinking ahead, which is good, but you're thinking ahead of the computer, which is bad. Within the scope of `deposit`, `answer` doesn't exist yet, so it has no idea what you're talking about when you ask whether it `=="D"`. It *should* throw an error, which you can solve a number of ways:

1. You could put everything into the `transaction` function (please don't do this)
2. You could pass `answer` to *both* `deposit` and `withdraw`, separately, and let them figure out what they each want to do with it (again, nope)
3. You could, keeping things at about this level of complexity, run your `if` statements from `deposit` and `withdraw` in the `transaction` function instead, and call whichever of the two matches up (this sounds good, let's do this).

To take option 3, you would actually pull the `if` statements from each function and then tell each one to run their corresponding functions... and that's it. Like

```
if answer[0].lower()=="d":
    deposit()
elif answer[0].lower()=="w":
    withdraw()
else:
    print("I'm confused, this is not fun anymore.")
```

## deposit

Your `deposit` function isn't retaining the new balance when people deposit money. You mentioned this is a simple ATM program so I'm trying to limit the scope of functionality I would expect in grading something like this, and ultimately you probably know better than anyone on StackOverflow what your assignment demands, but do *think about* how you would keep the new balance :)

## withdraw

Same as all of the stuff from before

## end

I'm *pretty* sure `exit` doesn't take arguments (in other words, you can't leave a parting message on your way out). Just `print` your goodbye and then `exit` quietly so to speak.

I haven't brought up things like function parameters or classes (let alone class attributes or methods), any of which could really broaden the scope and complexity of your assignment, but at the same time would make it much more interesting and rewarding to code. You seem to be thinking procedurally, which (in my opinion) is good for getting your arms around how a computer works through things. Keep at it; someday you'll look back at this code and think about how you could have optimized and abstracted certain things so much :P

Comment: Thank you very much for that info!!! Actually, I have also been having issues with keeping the balance, but I didn't want to seem to needy by asking about this :P

Comment: There are advantages to figuring things out for yourself (and I won't deprive you of those advantages), but you'll probably find that making `balance` a `global` variable will help for some of the same reasons that making `answer` a global helped. I should warn, however, that global variables are generally considered *bad* to use, largely because they're so far-reaching.

Comment: I see, I just have one more question. I have another file that I am using to experiment with your suggestions, but the program keeps ending after it shows the current balance. It won't let me select w to withdraw, it stops the program after current balance.

Comment: Actually, I found that the transaction part is showing up in a separate window behind the pin number/account balance window, heh. I also just noticed I might have been running the programs wrong, I have been using the Python Launcher instead of the run module option in IDLE @_@

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this, you can either make answer a global variable. Not recommended, but an option or you can pass it to the function deposit by typing and to call it use deposit(answer)
`def deposit(answer):`

If you decide to use calling functions instead of just having every function called no matter what it makes your program more computer friendly.

Also one last thing is you might run into some problems because you have balance as the name of a function along with an int variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `answer` only inside functions. Add

```
answer  = 0
```

above the `account()` function and wherever you use answer, add

```
global answer
```

in that function. This is becasus, the scope of `answer` is limited to particular function and not outside the function. If you use a global variable, it can be used in any function.